Redefine the highest version in Gradle for resolution conflict
As far as I understand, when Gradle gets 2 conflicting versions in chooses the higher one by default. It also considers purely numeric versions "higher" than alphanumeric to ones.
This means that between versions: 53 and release-54 it'll select 53.
I want to override this behavior in one of the following ways (all are acceptable):

For all dependencies, preform a purely string-based comparison with no preference to purely numeric versions.
For a specific organization, do the same.
For all dependencies, prefer versions starting with release- to ones that don't have that (keep sorting by higher version after that).
For a specific organization, do the same.

I'm also open to other suggestions.
Please verify your solution works, or comment that it is unverified.
